# Business Catalyst: Is it possible to submit the Password Retrieve Request form and display the resulting Password Retrieve Conformation page via AJAX?

Tags: javascript, ajax, business-catalyst

I'd like to streamline the process by which website users sign up, login and retrieve/reset their password on an Adobe Business Catalyst website.

I have managed to get the Secure Zone Login Form to submit using AJAX. I am also using jQuery.load to get the HTML from the Password Retrieve Request system page and insert it on my login page so users don't have to leave the page to retrieve their password.

Next step I'd like to do is to submit the Password Retrieve Request form via AJAX and prevent the browser from loading the page that gets loaded by default (`mysite.com/_System/SystemPages/PasswordRetrieveConfirmation`) but get the data on that page with AJAX and display that on the current page.

Is this possible?

The Password Retrieve Request page and corresponding form is as follows:

```
<div class="system-message">

    <h3>Forgot Password?</h3>

    <p id="tokenExpiredMessage" class="error {tag_tokenExpired}">ERROR: Your password reset token has expired. Please request a new one by filling in the form below.</p>

    <p id="invalidUsernameMessage" class="error {tag_invalidUsername}">ERROR: The email address or username you provided does not exist.</p>

    <p>Enter your email address or username below and we'll send you instructions on how to reset it.</p>

    <form action="/LostPasswordProcess.aspx" method="post" name="catseczonelpform" id="lost-password-form">

        <input type="text" maxlength="255" id="SZUsername" name="Username" class="cat_textbox_small" placeholder="Email Address / Username" />

        <input type="submit" value="RETRIEVE" class="cat_button" />

    </form>

</div>
```

I assume the processing is all happening server-side as I don't see any JS.

Answer (score 2):

The endpoint is `/LostPasswordProcess.aspx`, and it expects a `POST` request with one field: `Username`.

Here's how I'd do it (with jQuery, for brevity):

```
var pwResetRequest = $.post(
    '/LostPasswordProcess.aspx', 
    { Username: 'ClementMandragora' }
);

pwResetRequest.then(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    // do your thing with the response html
});
```

Note that we have limited access to the response headers, so to tell programatically whether the reset request was successful would seem to require parsing the response.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this is possible with BC. I tried using AJAX but it doesn't work as it threw an error and reloaded the page.

You can try asking on the [BC Forums](https://forums.adobe.com/community/business_catalyst) to see if anyone there can assist. Otherwise, I would ensure the system page matches your site and not worry about it too much.